# Do react native layout components get compiled differently to the logic?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, babeljs

I'm trying to understand the difference if React native view/layout code is compiled differently to logic code. I understand that JS logic is kept in a JS bundle and communicates with the native app via a bridge but do the layout components e.g.  get compiled to their native counterparts while building the app so they are already in a native format when installed on a device, or are these native views being created on the fly as well when the JS code communicates with the native device?

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript code and the native components in React Native are two separate things that communicate with one another over a bridge.

1. JavaScript code
2. native components
3. bridge communication

During the build process, the JavaScript-defined layout components are not compiled into native code. Rather, native UI elements are generated dynamically depending on your React component hierarchy and are interpreted at runtime. JavaScript logic can be seamlessly integrated with native user interface elements since the bridge facilitates communication between the JavaScript code and native components.

Comment: Ok, thanks thats what I was trying to clarify whether even the UI components get generated at runtime or whether they are prebuilt into native components and its just the logic which remains as JS. So essentially all the react native code remains as JS and in a simple static page app, the entire app would just be JS with minimal native interaction.